# How do clear an image multiple times?

Tags: javascript, html, image, function, loops

```html
<head>        
        <script>     
        function changeCounter(){
        var originalAmount=parseInt(document.getElementById("number").value);
        quarterAmount=Math.floor(originalAmount/25)
        for(var i=0; i<quarterAmount;i++){
                image1=new Image();
                image1.src="quarter.png";
            document.body.appendChild(image1);
            }
        }
        </script>
        </head>
        <body>
        <button onclick="changeCounter();">=</button>
       </body>
```

What I'm trying to figure out is how to loop through the images and clear them all. I am aware of document.body.removeChild method but I can't figure out a way to clear them all using that method. Is there a way to check if there are currently images being displayed and clear them so that it can make room for a new input?

Comment: You didn't tell us what the issue is with oyur current code - Also: when you say "clear" do you mean "remove"?

Comment: Sorry, yes. That's what I meant to say. "remove"

Answer (score 2):

Do `new Set(document.images).forEach((image) => {image.remove()})`.

Comment: Is there a way to use the same function so that it both produces and removes images? I  want to know if there's a way to check if there are already images on display so that it could remove them and display new ones for a new input.

Comment: @AlkaneProductions put this line as a first line in your function `changeCounter`

Comment: [document.images](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/images) is read-only; so, you cannot add images to it.  However, you can use ```document.images.length > 0``` to check if there are already images on display.